# R solving hackerrank challenge

Tags: r

I would like to solve [the challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bday-gift). The language of my preference is R. I am not sure how to receive input. On hackerrank coding window it says that

```
"# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT"
```

So far I am used to receiving input by using

```
v1 <- readline("Enter two integers: ")
```

How should i receive input on hackerrank? I tried to see solved examples but couldn't find any solved examples.

---

**update 1**

Below code works in R. Only problem is number of steps and ball values are not provided from keyboard input. We have to update them manually on line 1 and line2. How could I get update below solution so that it works on hackerrank?

```
steps=4
ball_numbers=c(1,2,2,2)
d=as.data.frame(c(0,1))

    for (i in (1:(length(ball_numbers)-1)))
    {
      assign(x = paste("A", i, sep = ""),value = c(0,1))
      e <- as.data.frame(get(paste("A", i, sep = "")))
      colnames(e) <- paste("A", i, sep="")
      d <- merge(d,e)
}


d=as.matrix(t(d))
answer=sum(ball_numbers %*% d)/ncol(d)
```

---

**update2**

Below code produces correct answer

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
nums <- read.table("/dev/stdin", sep=" ");
nums <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(t(nums)))

steps=nums[1]
ball_numbers=nums[2:length(nums)]
d=as.data.frame(c(0,1))

for (i in (1:(length(ball_numbers)-1)))
{
    assign(paste("A", i, sep = ""),value = c(0,1))
    e <- as.data.frame(get(paste("A", i, sep = "")))
    colnames(e) <- paste("A", i, sep="")
    d <- merge(d,e)
}


d=as.matrix(t(d))
#answer=as.numeric(format(round(sum(ball_numbers %*% d)/ncol(d),1),nsmall=1))
answer = print(format(sum(ball_numbers %*% d)/ncol(d),nsmall=1, digits = 1), quote = F)
write.table(as.numeric(answer), sep = "", append=T, row.names = F, col.names = F,quote = FALSE,)
```

I get below output

```
[1] 2.0
2
```

which is different from expected output which is below. How can i modify my code to get the correct format of output

```
2.0
```

Comment: can u use `readLines(file("stdin"))`

Comment: would it be possible to show example? i used your line and typed multiple numbers. But still it expects more input...i am not sure how to use it

Comment: Have you tried pressing enter when you're done typing?

Comment: Yes, I pressed enter, but it just takes cursor to the next line :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look at the "warmup".

```
data <- suppressWarnings(read.table("stdin", sep=" "));
```

Alternatively you can use

```
data <- suppressWarnings(readLines(file("stdin")))
```

[Also Refer this page in hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/environment/sample-problem)

Comment: thanks, that helped. Would you able to help me with update 2?

Comment: Not at my computer now to test but my guess is to 1) not print your answer and 2) you specify digits when you print your answer but you don't actually save that value to the table. So your table value is 2 instead of the correct 2.0

Comment: I am still not clear...would appreciate your help once you are back to your computer

Comment: Sorry for the very basic question - what is "stdin" here? Is it an input file that we have to create? If yes, how?

Answer (score 6):

I faced the similar issue for reading input in R in hackerrank . Then to use readLines i used following :

```
input<-file('stdin', 'r')
x <- readLines(input, n=1)
```

If u again want to read another data y use same approach :

```
y <- readLines(input, n=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#---this solves the problem
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
nums <- suppressWarnings(readLines(file("stdin")))
#nums <- suppressWarnings(readLines(file("new.txt")))
nums <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(t(nums)))
class(nums) <- "numeric"

steps=nums[1]
ball_numbers=nums[2:length(nums)]
d=as.data.frame(c(0,1))

for (i in (1:(length(ball_numbers)-1)))
{
  assign(paste("A", i, sep = ""),value = c(0,1))
  e <- as.data.frame(get(paste("A", i, sep = "")))
  colnames(e) <- paste("A", i, sep="")
  d <- merge(d,e)
}


d=as.matrix(t(d))
answer=sum(ball_numbers %*% d)/ncol(d)
write.table(cat(format(answer, nsmall=1), sep="\n"), sep = "", append=T, row.names = F, col.names = F)
```

Comment: did you fix your own problem? Also in the future, you'll get a much better response to your questions if you ask one question per post. After answering the original question people are very unlikely to check back for updates that are actually additional questions. If the original answer I provided answered your original question please click the checkmark next to the answer so that others know the question is closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
con = file('stdin', open ='r')
input  = readLines(con)
z = c()
for(i in 2:length(input)){
  z = c(z, as.numeric(input[[i]]))
}

cat(format(round(sum(z)/2, 1), nsmall = 1), sep = "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

A very handy one-liner to read in from standard input is the `scan` function, for instance:

```
text <- scan(file = 'stdin', what = 'character', sep = '\r')
```